# Twig: Selecting certain blocks and rendering them

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am intergrating the twig templating engine into a PHP application. In particular, I would like to use the twig engine to render forms.

Having had a look at how symfony2 uses twig to render form widgets, they have a huge template file which contains all the widgets like so:

```
(...)
{% block password_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('password') %}
    {{ block('field_widget') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock password_widget %}

{% block hidden_widget %}
    {% set type = type|default('hidden') %}
    {{ block('field_widget') }}
{% endblock hidden_widget %}

{% block email_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('email') %}
    {{ block('field_widget') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock email_widget %}

{% block test_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
   <div>
     {{test}}
   <div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock test_widget %}

(...)
```

The question I have is how can I "grab" blocks out of this template and render them?

So far, I am able to load the template, and call get blocks to get all the blocks:

```
twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => 'cache'));
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('view\form_div_layout.html.twig');
//var_dump($template->getBlocks()); //try getting all blocks
$template->displayBlock('test_widget', array('test' => 'test'));
echo $template->render();
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to render just the 'test_widget' block in this case. What should I do to retrieve the 'test_widget' block from the template and then insert it into a different template to render the whole form?

Comment: this might work for me, can you share how you iinstantiated, or used `$loader` please?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out that one should use `$template->renderBlock('blockname', array('test' => 'test'));` instead. This will make twig render that block and then return a string containing the markup for that block. One can then use echo to display it or insert it into other templates.

Full example:

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array('/my-template-root'));
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('view\form_div_layout.html.twig');
$result = $template->renderBlock('blockname', array('test' => 'test'));
echo $result;
```

Comment: what is the use of the second parameter?

Comment: The second parameter is an array of variables that appear in the template. For example, `{{ test }}`.

Comment: im having a very hard time figuring out this part, because when i do this, im am getting an exception, as if there needs to be a USE statyement too.  are you saying that this is alreday extended/embedded an no USE statement if needed to extend the twig engine?  even if i do, it doesnt work.

Comment: @BrianThomas What is the exception message you are getting?

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigEngine::loadTemplate()` the last try i used this.  `$twig = $this->get('templating');`
        `$template = $twig->loadTemplate('MyCoreBundle:Default:fireEmail.html.twig'); // Define your own schema;`  i just dont know how to access twig properly in my core controller i think.  it does extend the `Controller` too.

Comment: well, i see i was loading TimedTwigEngine there, lol.  i dont think that was the exact error.  however, my latest im trying it this way, and  i cant get anything to work yet.. i see this, and wonder if this is what im loking for. maybe somebody can clarify.. github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8517 and 
i found two good links, that might contain my answer, anybody know which of these might be the correct usage? http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Form/… http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Templating/…,

Comment: `$twig = $this->get('twig');`
        `$renderedSubject  = $twig->renderBlock('subject',   $emailSubject);  ` `Call to undefined method Twig_Environment::renderBlock()`  isnt there one thats not part of a form class anywhere to just RENDER the block in teh back end controller?

Comment: @BrianThomas: I am not using symfony, but I have updated my answer to  contain a full example of how it could work. This is where the `renderBlock()` method lives: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/Template.php#L198

Comment: @BrianThomas With symfony you would need to do `$twig = $this->get('twig');` `$template = $twig->loadTemplate('view\form_div_layout.twig');` `$subject = $template->renderBlock('subject', (array) $emailSubject);`  See FOSUserBundle example https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Mailer/TwigSwiftMailer.php#L67

Comment: use load() instead, it's not @internal unlike loadTemplate()

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Symfony and want to be able to still have access to the global variables (`app`, `app.user`, etc) then this works great:

```php
private function renderBlock($template, $block, $params = [])
{
    /** @var \Twig\Environment $twig */
    $twig = $this->get('twig');
    /** @var \Twig\TemplateWrapper $template */
    $template = $twig->load($template);

    return $template->renderBlock($block, $twig->mergeGlobals($params));
}
```

I just added this has a private function on my controller. Works great. Thanks to @F21 for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: use `load()` instead, it's not @internal unlike `loadTemplate()`

Answer (score 3):

This is great!  I also wanted to add that there is a `hasBlock` function which allows you to do validation before you attempt to do the template rendering.  This allows you to validate the template is built as expected, or in my case have optional blocks.  For what it's worth, here's an example from one of my console apps which sends notification emails

```
        $templateContent = $this->getContainer()->get('twig')->loadTemplate('FTWGuildBundle:AuctionNotification:notificationEmail.html.twig');
        $body = $templateContent->renderBlock('body', array('siteDomain' => $siteClient->getSiteDomain(), 'staticContentDomain' => $siteClient->getStaticContentDomain(), 'batch' => $batch->getNotifications(), 'auction_notification_lockout_period' => $this->getContainer()->getParameter('auction_notification_lockout_period')));
        $subject = ($templateContent->hasBlock("subject")
            ? $templateContent->renderBlock("subject", array('batchSize' => $batch->getSize(), 'batch' => $batch))
            : "Auction House Notifications");
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: hasBlock won't work if the template extends or embeds a parent block.

see
https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/450