# Is there a way to include template and hide some of his block

Tags: symfony

Maybe this question can be transferred into two questions:

if i have include a template in at .html.twig, may i control to show or hide some of the block in the included twig?

Could i extend an twig from  several twig layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, your description is a little vague so I'll stick to the question.

You can solve this problem with a template in the middle.

You can not include a template directly and modify its blocks AFAIK, but you can create a **second template which extends the first one** and deletes the blocks, then **include the second template** where you need.

Suppose this is the template you wanted to include originally:

```
<div>
    This is the template you want to include (articleDetails.html.twig)
    {% block article %}
        This is some content you want to delete
    {% endblock article %}
</div>
```

You can try creating a second template which extends it like this:

```
{% extends 'articleDetails.html.twig' %}

{# This is template emptyArticle.html.twig, it deletes the article block #}
{% block article %}
{% endblock article %}
```

Then instead of including articleDetails, you can **include this second template** (emptyArticle), and you are going to get the contents of the first one but without the contents of the article block.
You can do this with any number of blocks.

Comment: this is extends, not include. include means --include, like : {% include 'AcmeArticleBundle:Article:articleDetails.html.twig' with {'article': article} %} see in the site of symfony. So my question is "if we can hide something like we extends a template?"

Comment: You are supposed to **include** the second template, please read the description carefully.

Comment: Note, you can use {{ parent() }} or even {% set parentBlock = parent() %} to render or get access to a string of the contents of the parent block, in a child block and then manipulate that programatically.

Answer (score 6):

Me and one coworker just discovered one cool thing which is somehow connected with this question.

For example, if you want to render block just when you call `renderBlock` (Twig method) method and not when you extend a template, you can use this trick.

`{% if false %}
    {% block subject %}
        subject_message
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}`

When you call `renderBlock` (like here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/7580461/922165), this block will get rendered because the method does not care about the other statements.

But, when you extend - this block will be never shown.

This is for example helpful when you have some basic default e-mail template that other e-mail templates are extending. You can wrap some default e-mail subject in the block, and this block does not need to be shown on the other templates.

Answer (score 1):

This is way past the 'expiration date' of this question but in case others might have a similar question in mind, I solved this by using twig variables in the included template.

```
{% set myConditionalBlockToShow %}
    <span>some interesting things {{ withVariable }}</span>
{% endset %}

{% if myCondition %}
    {{ myConditionalBlockToShow }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables in an include

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

And in template.html, you check the value of 'foo' and show/hide your block depending of the value

Or if you have more complex template, you can split them and call them in a controller.

```
{% render url('latest_articles', { 'view': 2 }) %}

public function recentArticlesAction($view = 1) {
    // make a database call or other logic
    // to get the "$max" most recent articles
    $articles = ...;

    if($view == 2) {
        return $this->render(
           'AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentList.html.twig',
            array('articles' => $articles)
        );
    }
    return $this->render(
        'AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentList2.html.twig',
        array('articles' => $articles)
    );
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers